# Neo4j integration test failing on EOFException when using data fixtures

Tags: neo4j

I'm building a Neo4j (2.2.3) unmanaged extension and trying to run integration tests. Following the example in the docs, I have:

```
@Test
public void testInsertInitiative() throws Exception { 
    try ( ServerControls server = TestServerBuilders.newInProcessBuilder()
        .withExtension("/graph/initiative", InitiativeController.class)
        .withFixture(TestFixtures.foobar(x, y, z))
        .newServer() )
    {
        HTTP.Response response = //... I can't get this far... 
    }
}
```

However, whenever I include a data fixture, the test fails to initialize on a:

```
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
at org.neo4j.harness.internal.Fixtures.ensureInstallSuccessful(Fixtures.java:127)
at org.neo4j.harness.internal.Fixtures.applyTo(Fixtures.java:110)
at org.neo4j.harness.internal.InProcessServerBuilder.newServer(InProcessServerBuilder.java:75)
at org.mycompany.myproject.MyTestClass.myTest(MyTestClass.java:87)
```

If I comment out the inclusion of the fixture, the test runs as expected, so the problem is definitely there (also deducible from the stack trace...). I've verified that my TestFixtures method generates a valid cypher statement by c/p'ing it into the console and executing it there successfully. I've also tried replacing it with a simple

```
.withFixture("CREATE (:foo)")
```

and had the same result.

This is happening both in version 2.2.3 and 2.2.2, and happens with or without loading my extension.

Following the debug trail down a couple of layers, I've found that the response received by the call to `ClientResponse response = client.handle( req )` at line 109 in /harness/internal/Fixtures.java has a status of Server Error and an empty entity, which I assume is resulting in the EOF...

But why the server error? Again, I c/p'd the payload from the call made by the client there and posted it (successfully) to a non-test server.

Here are my pom dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <neo4j.version>2.2.3</neo4j.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test-jar</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you share your source code?

Comment: @StefanArmbruster - [I just posted a SSCCE to github](https://github.com/drew-moore/neoIntegrationFixturesFail) that reproduces it - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of this dependency will make the test pass in your SSCCE:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hmm - indeed it does. I hadn't tried taking that one out because it's one of the two that are [explicitly mentioned in the doc as being necessary](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.3/server-unmanaged-extensions.html#intro-unmanaged-extensions)...

Comment: don't remember for sure, but I think the dependency above is required on JDK6. Newer JDKs might have this on board automatically.

Comment: Interesting - if that's the case, they really ought to make a note of that in the doc...